# Identify the UI

Tags: user-interface

The first computer I used at home — this was in the late 1980s, I guess — was an [IBM PC AT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer/AT) running [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS). But when I turned on the computer, a screen came up with a menu of applications. It looked something like this:

```
    List 1     |      Games        |    Another list
---------------+-------------------+---------------------
  WordPerfect  |     Tetris        |  Quicken
  Something    |     Whatever      |  Foo
  Another      |     Another       |  Bar

    List 4     |      List 5       |    One more list
---------------+-------------------+---------------------
  Whatever     |     Something     |  Baz
  Blah Blah    |     Whatever      |  Xyzzy
  Another      |     Another       |  Qqqqq
```

These were selected using the keyboard. There was also some way to escape to the DOS prompt.

Does anyone know what UI-program this was?

Comment: This type of question is considered off-topic for SU.  Please check out [Are “Guessing Game” type questions allowed on SU?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6073/are-guessing-game-type-questions-allowed-on-su) for an explanation.

Comment: Also, maybe [this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=dos+menu+systems&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=2n6SUdL6E4PSywGjq4GgCA&ved=0CC4QsAQ) will help you. :)

Comment: @techie007, good to know. That should be added to [the FAQ list under "and it is not about"](http://superuser.com/faq#questions). (I *did* check that list before posting this question.)

Comment: I can see why you'd suggest that.  Feel free to add a comment/suggestion/question about that over on Meta.superuser.com. :)

Comment: @msh210 - There is no way of knowing what program you used.  The market was huge and everyone copied everyone else looking for that additional 0.05% share.

Answer (score 2):

There were several programs that had this sort of UI. The market for menu programs for DOS was pretty large. It's hard to tell exactly what one was on the one you used, but there are many similar programs out there. I've used a few, myself (some mouse-driven, and some not).